# How to make spring checkboxes checked by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE. I have this field in my command object ...

```
public Set<EventFeed> getUserEventFeeds() {
    return this.userEventFeeds;
}
```

On my Spring JSP page, I want to display a checkbox list of all possible event feeds, and then have checked checkboxes if the user has one in his set.  I want to have some special HTML formatting around each checkbox, so I'm trying ...

```
<form:form method="Post" action="eventfeeds.jsp" commandName="user">
    ...
        <c:forEach var="eventFeed" items="${eventFeeds}">
        <tr>
            <td><form:checkbox path="userEventFeeds" value="${eventFeed}"/></td>
            <td>${eventFeed.title}</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    ...
```

However, the items aren't getting checked by default if one is in the set.  How do I do this?  Here is the binder I'm using in my controller class ...

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(EventFeed.class, new EventFeedEditor());
}

private class EventFeedEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(eventFeedsDao.findById(Integer.valueOf(text)));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        return ((EventFeed) getValue()).getId().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Dave, there is something called form:checkBoxes. You can try with that.

```
<form:checkboxes path="userEventFeeds" items="${eventFeeds}" itemLabel="id" itemValue="value"/>
```

My assumption here is you should have "id" and "value" defined in the EventFeed class.

I just tried this by having a String[] availableList and String[] selectedList. It works like charm. You can give a try as well.

Comment: Per my description in the question, I want to put additional HTML around each checkbox.  So can I still pull off the HTML I want (listed in the question) using form:checkboxes?  So far I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: You mean you want the table around that check box with check box label in one column and the check box in the adjacent column?

Comment: There is an attribute called "element" in the form:checkboxes tag, which by their documentation says "Specifies the HTML element that is used to enclose each 'input' tag with type 'checkbox'. Defaults to 'span'." You can refer the documentation here in this link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkboxes.

Comment: yes, I want to surrund the checkboxes with a td and then have other td's next to the checkbox.  Is it clear the kind of HTML I want from my question?  Also, regarding the link you sent, I can't see how to get to the HTML I want from the "element" attribute.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can surround the checkbox with the td with the "element" attribute. I am taking the sample code that i gave in my answer. You need to do something like <form:checkboxes path="userEventFeeds" items="${eventFeeds}" itemLabel="id" itemValue="value" element="td"/>, this will surround each checkbox with a td, but the checkbox will have its own title as well. If you dont supply this element attribute the default is the span. This you can see by viewing the html once your page is rendered. If you supply the element="td" then you can see each checkbox will have a td around.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't get me where I want to be.  For each eventfeed in "items", I want to have a table row (tr) and then within that, have a checkbox in a td, its title in another td, and a "Preview" link in a third td.  "form:checkboxes" doesn't give me that flexibility.  Even if you don't know the answer, let me know if you understand what I'm asking, b/c if not, I need to modify this question to make it clearer to all.

Comment: May be you can put this explanation in the question, because at first sight it was not clear at least for me. Now it clear. Before putting my comment yesterday i tried the way you explained here but i was not able to achieve that using "form:checkboxes", i thought you only want the td around the checkbox. I can suggest you one more method which is the conventional way of putting the checkbox like <input type="checkbox"/> but bind with <spring:bind/> (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html). This is old style of doing but this might fit your requirement.

Comment: It looks like input:checkbox is the only way to go.  Thanks for sticking with it.

Answer (score 9):

Interestingly this works:

```
<form:checkbox path="services" value="${type}" checked="checked"/>
```

Comment: It is better practice to set the default value of the particular field like Jhonathan suggested.  If, for whatever reason, you can't then this solution does work.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by placing selected default property true in your class

```
class User {
   boolean userEventFeeds = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both `form:checkboxes` and `form:checkbox` with the same data and the first works, the second doesn't. (Same release of Spring you have)

It looks like there was a [bug](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CHoQFjAH&url=https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-2164?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel&ei=FEb8T_K9JsHNtAboztHxBQ&usg=AFQjCNGNukefm1dYLI8o4dUwmDtiplrTXA&sig2=Jbulv91IvTMC0Uh7DfjVIQ) which, despite their claim, seems to be still there.

Answer (score 0):

For my usecase (reacting on stuff in a list that has nothing to do with the object being filled), this code worked:

(Please be aware that this is a last-resort kind of code, other solutions are most likely better suited.)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="jstl" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jstl:forEach var="listObject" items="${someList}">
  <jstl:if test="${listObject.active}">
    <form:checkbox path="active" checked="checked"/>
  </jstl:if>
  <jstl:if test="${!listObject.active}">
    <form:checkbox path="active"/>
  </jstl:if>
</jstl:forEach>
```